# How to change CSS tags dynamically?

Tags: css, reactjs, sass

Is there a way to change the `.accordionItem-123` number dynamically in the CSS when the `id` in JSX className changes - or can this be done in SASS?

**JSX**

```js
<AccordionItem
   key={id}
   className={`accordionItem-${id}`}
>
```

**CSS**

```
.accordionItem-123 { // dynamically change the number?
   background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Well, you need to specify all the CSS classes which you want to used.

Comment: How do you mean? I don't follow.

Comment: You don't need to do so, it's been auto-generated by tools in normal libs. You can't customize your style via this

Comment: You could probably with some JS trick, but have you considered using a selector without the id instead? Such as `[class*="accordionItem-"]`

Comment: Thank you guys, doesn't seem like we can change the CSS this ways. Thank you for all your input!